# Sending a $routeParam to the server through a service Angular

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

You will have to bear with me because I am a self-taught noob. 
I have a php page on my server that need a $_get variable to sort the data on the server side rather than the client. I am using routeParams in Angular for the variable to send over. This works, however it only works when you refresh the webpage. Please can someone help me as my head hurts from hitting the wall.

Controller:

```
    app.controller('JuiceController', ['$scope', 'juices', function($scope, juices) {
        juices.success(function(data){
        $scope.juices = data;
        });
    }]);
```

Service:

```
    app.factory('juices', ['$http', '$routeParams',function($http, $routeParams) {
return $http.get('http://madcow-app.dev/application/backend/api/products.php', {
    params: {prod: $routeParams.prod}
    })
     .success(function(data) {
       return data;
    })
     .error(function(err){
        return err;
    });
   }]);
```

Html output (juice view):

```
    <div class="juice-wrap" ng-repeat="juice in juices">
<div class="juice-img"><img ng-src="{{ juice.imgpath }}" width="163" height="176" alt=""/></div>
<div class="juice-rght">
  <div class="juice-title">{{ juice.name }}</div>
  <div class="juice-desc">{{ juice.descrip }}</div>
```

Route provider

```
    $routeProvider
.when('/', {
templateUrl: 'script/views/home.html'
})
.when('/categories/', {
controller: 'CatController',
templateUrl: 'script/views/categories.html'
})
.when('/juice/:prod', {
controller: 'JuiceController',
templateUrl: 'script/views/juice.html'
})
.when('/events/', {
controller: 'EventController',
templateUrl: 'script/views/events.html'
})
.when('/qr/', {
templateUrl: 'script/views/qr.html'
})
.when('/feedback/', {
templateUrl: 'script/views/feedback.html'
})
.otherwise({
redirectTo: '/'
```

php function outputs json (this is outputted to the php controller below and takes the category id as a variable:)

```
    return json_encode($results);
```

To the php controller (this is the page that the angular service/factory pulls the json array of products from:

```
    <?php
    include "../../init.php";
    if (isset($_GET['prod']))
    {
    echo $MC->Api->getProductsApi($_GET['prod']);
    }
    else
    {
    echo 'error';
    }
```

This is the category html:

```
    <div class="cat-btn" ng-repeat="cat in cats">
<a href="#/juice/{{cat.catid}}">
  <img ng-src="{{ cat.imgpath }}" width="363" height="195" alt=""/>
  <div class="cat-btn-text"> {{ cat.name }} </div>
</a>
```

basically what I want to achieve is when a user clicks a category in the frontend, angular routes to the product view using the category id as a filter for the php function to populate the json output with only the juices in that category.

I'm not sure if I should be doing it this way around, or whether I need to hit it from another angle. Please bear in mind that i am a complete javascript noob and laymans would be great for the answer.

Thank you in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

Factory:

```
app.factory('juices', [
    '$http', '$routeParams', function ($http, $routeParams) {
        var self = this;

        function getJuices() {
            $http.get('http://madcow-app.dev/application/backend/api/products.php', {
                params: {prod: $routeParams.prod}
                })
                .success(function (data) {
                    self.juices = data.data;
                })
                .error(function (err) {

                });
        }

        return {
            getJuices: getJuices,
           juices: self.juices
        }
    }
]);
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('JuiceController', [
    '$scope', 'juices', function ($scope, juices) {
        juices.getJuices();
        $scope.$watch(function () {
            return juices.juices
        }, function (newJuices, oldJuices) {
            // This is triggered when juices.juices changes
            // newJuices containes the juices retrieved from server
            // This is needed because it is asynchronous
        });
    }
]);
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the super quick response. I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work. It will be me though. Do I now need to change my ng-repeat to look for new data?

Comment: in your php file, at the very begining, if you do 

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_GET);
echo "</pre>";

Do you get the data that you sent with $http ?

Comment: No, but it doesn't do it with my existing code either. I should also state that the php file echos out a json array for the controller to display in angular.

Comment: Update your question with more code, it is too vague for me to help.

Comment: Hope that update helps, i really appreciate the help Andrew. Let me know if you need any other info.

Comment: No problem ! So clicking something in /categories/ redirects to juices/:prod
, the number is in the url after the user clicks ?
$routeParams.prod is properly set befor the GET request ?

Comment: Yes that is correct, so once you click a category the url would be something like http://madcow-app.dev/application/app/#/juice/15 15 being the cat_id then server will then pull all products with a cat_id of 15

Comment: Since this logic is only applied to the juice view, try ommiting the factory and doing your $http call in the juice controller. Then print what comes out of the response. Also, make sure get variables work serverside, because some url re-writing MVC frameworks don't always support that